# PHP functions are not working in /var/www/html/domain.com/public_html

Tags: php

Can someone guide me on this issue?

Actually I'm trying to make Apache **.php** connect to **MySQL (phpmyadmin)server** for user validation, but looks like the php function is not responding and It refresh to the same page after clicking the submit button.

Pinging from apache server to MySQL server - Working
telnet to MySQLServerIP:3306 - Working

When I did info.php "phpinfo();" it works fine from `/var/www/html/domain.com/public_html/info.php`, which means I can browse.

Comment: This is from Ubuntu Server 16.04 actually. From my hosting server its working fine but from Ubuntu it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed all required binaries/plugins to run php/mysal/apache together. Following is installation commands, do run them and it will install any missing binaries.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

If still doesn't work, then do let me know. Will guide further on solving.

Comment: I did install and all are up-to date but still the same. When I did info.php "phpinfo();" it works fine from the var/www/html/domain.com/public_html/info.php, means I can browse.

Comment: It works now, after upgrade to php7.0

Comment: I will update answer with php7 then.